# Why can I not pass my delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

How can I pass the value of `didTap` to `ReminderViewController` using `delegates` ? Here is my code from `CustomCell` which has `didTap`

```
protocol BEMCheckBoxDelegate {

func checkBox(cell: CustomCell)

}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: BEMCheckBoxDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {

    print("Checkbox is \(checkBox.on)")
    self.delegate?.checkBox(cell: self)

}
```

Then in my `ReminderViewController` :

```
func checkBox(cell: CustomCell) {
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else{
    return
    }
    print("Button tapped on row \(indexPath.row)")

    let task=tasks[indexPath.row]
    task.checkDone="on"
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can just extend your protocol function:

```
protocol BEMCheckBoxDelegate {

    func checkBox(cell: CustomCell, isOn: Bool)
}
```

and then in the Cell you just call it like:

```
self.delegate?.checkBox(cell: self, isOn: checkBox.on)
```

and don't forget to change your function in ReminderViewController:

```
func checkBox(cell: CustomCell, isOn: Bool) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `self.delegate?.checkBox(cell: self, isOn: checkBox.on)` this goes in my `didTap` ?

Comment: why is it not working?
please check:
 - is the function `didTap ` even called?
 - does `print("Checkbox is \(checkBox.on)")` even print the correct value?
 - do you set the delegate when you create the `CustomCell `?

Comment: Yes I get the print statement in my console.

Comment: Please make sure, that you set the delegate correctly, you should have a something like this in your `ReminderViewController `: `customCell.delegate = self`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139072/discussion-between-kondeichmann-and-s-verma).